# Модификация циферблата часов на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть часы, подскажите как можно вместо линий показывающих деления часов, вставить цифры?
Не до конца понимаю, как написать такую функцию..

```js
 function clockPainting() {
  var now = new Date();
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var hr = now.getHours();

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.save(); // помещаем текущий контекст в стэк

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
  ctx.translate(75, 75);
  ctx.scale(0.4, 0.4);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
   ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
   ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
   ctx.lineTo(120, 0);
  }

  ctx.stroke(); // нарисовали то, что ранее описали
  ctx.restore(); // достаем последний сохраненный контекст из стэка

  ctx.save();
  // рисуем часовую стрелку, вращая холст
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 6) * hr +
   (Math.PI / 360) * min +
   (Math.PI / 21600) * sec);
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20, 0);

  // линия почти до часовых меток
  ctx.lineTo(80, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();

  // минутная стрелка
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 30 * min) +
   (Math.PI / 1800) * sec);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-28, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(112, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();

  // секундная стрелка
  ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI / 30);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#D40000"; // цвет контура
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 6;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-30, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(83, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.restore();
 }
 window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(clockPainting, 1000); // функция, перерисовывающая часы
  //через равные промежутки времени
 }
```

```html
        <canvas id="canvas" height="150" width="150"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function clockPainting() {
  var now = new Date();
  var sec = now.getSeconds();
  var min = now.getMinutes();
  var hr = now.getHours();

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.save(); // помещаем текущий контекст в стэк

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
  ctx.translate(75, 75);
  ctx.scale(0.4, 0.4);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();

  // рисуем деления часов
  /*
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
    ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(120, 0);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  */

  // рисуем статичный циферблат
  var ang;
  var radius = 150;
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.font = radius * 0.25 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (var num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
    ang = num * (Math.PI / 6);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
    ctx.fillText((num).toString(), 3, 5);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText((num).toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }

  ctx.stroke(); // нарисовали то, что ранее описали
  ctx.restore(); // достаем последний сохраненный контекст из стэка

  ctx.save();
  // рисуем часовую стрелку, вращая холст
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 6) * hr +
    (Math.PI / 360) * min +
    (Math.PI / 21600) * sec);
  ctx.lineWidth = 14;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20, 0);

  // линия почти до часовых меток
  ctx.lineTo(80, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();

  // минутная стрелка
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 30 * min) +
    (Math.PI / 1800) * sec);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-28, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(112, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();

  // секундная стрелка
  ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI / 30);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#D40000"; // цвет контура
  ctx.fillStyle = "#D40000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 6;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-30, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(83, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.restore();
}
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(clockPainting, 1000); // функция, перерисовывающая часы
  //через равные промежутки времени
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="150" width="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!